# Set Header as 'application/json' to all actions in controller YII

Tags: json, yii

I am creating a rest api using yii framework so the basic output format would be json....

I want all actions in a controller to have header content-type as 'application-json'.

I tried to put it in beforeFilter function in the controller but it didn't work.

Can any one help me out...

Comment: Can you show the specific code you used? My suggestion would be to do this in `beforeAction()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `init()` function in the Controller class (*protected/components/Controller.php*). This will be called when any Controller/Action is called. Eg:

```
public function init(){
    if ($this->id == 1){
        // perform controller specific function
    }
}
```

The `$this->id` returns the controller id. You must obviously **replace the 1** in the code above with the relevant controller id for the controller you want the function to take place with

Comment: Just to wonder: why the superclass? Why not use the specific controller's `init()`? Or even a filter? Anyhow, then the OP would not need a condition on the `id`, right?